# Android adt is not working emulator is showing error.

Tags: android

i downloaded android adt (eclipse ide + android sdk), but when i tried to run it the this following error occurred:

```
[2013-07-02 21:51:47 - Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found
[2013-07-02 21:51:47 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-07-02 21:51:47 - Emulator] 
[2013-07-02 21:51:47 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate                           it in an unusual way.                  
[2013-07-02 21:51:47 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more   information.enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Eclipse:

> Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

Default emulator options: -**dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4**